# Printing Blank data when it has more data then a4 size

Tags: javascript, pdf, html2canvas, pdf-conversion

When my div has more data then a4 size page it generates blank PDF . although it is working fine when it has few data(under a4 size)

I have tried some other way but it doesnt print css

```
 $scope.ConvertToPDF = function () {
            debugger;
            $("#HideMe").hide();

            html2canvas(document.getElementById('exportthis'), {
                onrendered: function (canvas) {
                    var data = canvas.toDataURL();

                    var docDefinition = {
                        content: [{
                            image: data,
                            width: 500,
                            height:5000
                        }]
                    };
                    pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).download('TodaysReport' + ".pdf");



                }
            });
```

Comment: Would need to see the markup + css...

Comment: I am using a template which has bootstrap and I'm using angular javascript

Comment: .table-responsive {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    overflow-x: auto;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    -ms-overflow-style: -ms-autohiding-scrollbar;
}
   this is my datatable css

Comment: <tr ng-repeat="item in TodaysBooking"><td> some columns</td></tr> this is my html

Comment: suppose my table has 10 columns then it is pring=ting fine but when i have 100 columns(more then a4 size page then it is printing white page only)